# Is there something special about using blockchain technology in the public construction industry?

Tags: blockchain

The German federal parliament "Deutscher Bundestag" is discussing* a proposal to use blockchain technology in the public construction industry.

I see blockchain is a technology, something to solve technical problems, a tool.
And I am surprised that the German parliament, "Deutscher Bundestag", the highest parliament of Germany, discusses a technical tool.

Is there something special about using blockchain technology in the public construction industry of a country?
Is it somehow above a technology to solve a technical problem?

---

<sub>*It was discussed in 149. Sitzung des Deutschen Bundestag, 2020-03-05

The German transcript should become available in the next couple of days at

 https://pdok.bundestag.de/index.php?start=pp</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The original motivation for the discussion was the that some public building projects wildly exceeded their original budget and planned building time. Most famously the Berlin Brandenburg Airport.

I would think that is a technical problem.
What makes it political is that it is not yet solved, and it is very expensive.
So the point is the political pressure.

Practical effect of introducing a law about the topic would be a that the whole industry would introduce it, as opposed to most of the industry. That can create a full documentation of public building projects, as opposed to a documentation that is only partial, because in practice, one could assume that there are always parts that are missing. Simply because it most probably will  happen that somebody fails to do the task he should do, but is not formally forced to do.

The value of a complete chain of documentation has a much larger practical value to understand a building project, even if it is only after the fact.
An incomplete documentation could also intentionally miss fraudulent parts, that could be an obvious problem even in paper documentation.

As paper documentation, a fraud could be hidden after the fact. Using blockchain, a fraud needs to be planned as a fraudulent contract before.